# Get member attribute when validating using IValidatableObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using IValidatableObject to validate a complex object in the following scenario.

```
public class Foo {
    [Required]
    public Bar Foobar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IValidatableObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)  {
        // check if the current property instance is decorated with the Required attribute
        if(TheAboveConditionIsTrue) {
            // make sure the Name property is not null or empty
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, if not I'm happy to take comments on other ways of solving the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract base class for `Foo` that implements `IValidatableObject` and make its `Validate()` method virtual:

```
public abstract class FooBase : IValidatableObject
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public Bar Foobar { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        //Validate other properties here or return null
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(OtherProperty))
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("OtherProperty is required", new[] { "OtherProperty" }));

        return results;
    }
}
```

Now implement your base class as either `FooRequired` or `FooNotRequired`:

```
public class FooRequired : FooBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var result = base.Validate(validationContext).ToList();
        result.AddRange(Foobar.Validate(validationContext));
        return result;
    }
}

public class FooNotRequired : FooBase
{
    //No need to override the base validate method.
}
```

Your `Bar` class would still look something like this:

```
public class Bar : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Name is required", new[] { "Name" }));

        return results;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
FooBase foo1 = new FooRequired();
foo1.Validate(...);

FooBase foo2 = new FooNotRequired();
foo2.Validate(...);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow you here, you code seems to get all attributes on a specific type but I need to get the Foobar property and then check if this property has the required attribute not the Bar objects attributes.

Comment: It gets all properties and then gets all attributes on that property. If the property has a validation attribute, we get the property value `value = source.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(source, null);` and then perform the validation on that value.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my question but my problem is that I'm trying to use the IValidatableObject and validate the Name property based on an attribute in the Foo class. Your extension can most certainly be used if I have the Foo instance BUT I only have the Bar instance. So my question is, is it possible to check if validationContext.ObjectInstance "public Bar Foobar { get; set; }" has the required attribute and check if the Name is set, but only if the Foobar property has the required attribute. This should be done in the Bar class using IValidatableObject.Validate

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. In that case I would just have `Foo` implement `IValidatableObject` and the validate method on `Foo` just calls `this.Bar.Validate();`

Comment: After re-reading the post, I updated the answer to better fit your requirement.