# Self-contained component with validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model-binding

I have a model called **Foo** which has a property called **MyProp** of type **Bar**.
When I post this model to the controller I want the model binder to validate **MyProp** because it has the Required attribute just as it does with a string. I need this to be self-contained within the Bar class or as a separate class. I have tried to use the IValidatableObject on the **Bar** class but it seems like it's impossible to check if the **Foo** class has the **Required** attribute on **MyProp**? So now I'm out of options and need some help. Below is some sample code for my question.

```
public class Foo {
    [Required]
    public Bar MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution to my problem where I can use the built in required attribute and still get custom behavior. This is just some proof of concept code.

The model:

```
public class Page : IPageModel {
    [Display(Name = "Page", Prompt = "Specify page name...")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must specify a page name")]
    public PageReference PageReference { get; set; }
}
```

The model binder:

```
public class PageModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(bindingContext.ModelType)) {
            var attributes = property.Attributes;
            if (attributes.Count == 0) continue;
            foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
                if (attribute.GetType().BaseType == typeof(ValidationAttribute) && property.PropertyType == typeof(PageReference)) {
                    var pageReference = bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(bindingContext.Model, null) as PageReference;
                    Type attrType = attribute.GetType();
                    if (attrType == typeof (RequiredAttribute) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageReference.Name)) {
                        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(property.Name,
                            ((RequiredAttribute) attribute).ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

The model binder provider:

```
public class InheritanceAwareModelBinderProvider : Dictionary<Type, IModelBinder>, IModelBinderProvider {
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType) {
        var binders = from binder in this
                      where binder.Key.IsAssignableFrom(modelType)
                      select binder.Value;

        return binders.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And last the global.asax registration:

```
var binderProvider = new InheritanceAwareModelBinderProvider {
    {
        typeof (IPageModel), new PageModelBinder() }
    };
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(binderProvider);
```

The result: http://cl.ly/IjCS

So what do you think about this solution?

Comment: Model binder shouldn't be responsible for validation, it should only perform binding. Validators should perform validation. You should move your code to custom validator.

Comment: @JakubKonecki I have tried to move the code and use IValidatableObject but I can't figure out how to validate the Bar class based on an attribute in the Foo class. I think a model binder is the only way here but if there is another way, please let me know!

Comment: you don't need to validate `Bar` class, you want to validate `MyProp` property in `Foo`, don't you? All you need to do is to check if `MyProp` is `null`.

Comment: @JakubKonecki If the `Required` attribute is set on `MyProp` I want to validate `MyProp`, but I want the validation code inside `Bar`, so it's self-contained. I have another question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835974/get-member-attribute-when-validating-using-ivalidatableobject)

Comment: @JakubKonecki Can you please explain how you think I can solve this without a the solution I provided in this question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no html field called `MyProp` and MVC doesn't fire any validation for this property.

One way to achieve your goal is to get rid of `Bar` and create `Bar's` properties in `Foo`. You can use *AutoMapper* to minimize plumbing code to minimum.

Another solution is to write a custom validation attribute which validates against the `null` values and use it instead of `Required` attribute.

Comment: In my case I have made an object.cshtml editor template so there is an MyProp_Name html field. I'm not really satisfied with creating my own attribute but if there is no other way I have to go with that one. Maybe a custom modelbinder for the Bar class could do the job?

Comment: Model binder is not responsible for validation. You cannot validate your models through model binder.

Comment: I have a solution in answer 3 and I'm gladly taking comments.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Instead of using `[Required]`, try a custom `ValidationAttribute`

```
public class Foo {
    [RequiredBar]
    public Bar MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RequiredBar : ValidationAttribute {

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        Bar bar = (Bar)value;

        // validate. For example
        if (bar == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return bar.Name != null;
    }
}
```

### Solution Two:

Simply put `Required` on the corresponding required properties of Bar, For example

```
public class Foo {
    //[RequiredBar]
    public Bar MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution but I don't like using two different required attributes. I'm developing a small cms solution where third party developers will use this model to add required fields to their content. Is't there another way of doing this? Maybe a custom model binder for the Bar class?

Comment: @Marcus: I have added another solution.

Comment: The problem I have with the second solution is that the class Bar is a built in component in my cms so a third party developer can not add the required attribute. What do you think about my solution below?

Comment: Well, the solution bellow is pretty complex. But of course, does what you wanted to do. You should mark that as accepted.